# Response.Body.WriteAsync: The file could not be opened

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I fetch a file from external source, that returns the file in byte array.
Now I want to open the file in the browser.

This is what I do:

```
public async Task OpenFile()
{

    [...]
    byte[] pdf = externalResource.GetPdf();
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=MyFile.pdf");
    await Response.Body.WriteAsync(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
    Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    //await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
    return;
}
```

The first time I call OpenFile, the PDF-file is shown. But if I call OpenFile again or refresh the window, I get an "The PDF-file could not be opened" from the browser (freely translated from danish).

What am I missing? - and is there another (better) approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Agree - it is strange that with code shown it opens correctly the first time. Should be failing - you can't seek non-seekable streams (also it probably just failed server side but stream already sent to browser without a way to fail that).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov actually, if I remove the Seek, the code won't work the first time neither. That line makes it work the first time. Can you guide me in a direction to fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to write Response.Body.Seek section cause after you write any buffer data to response body, actual response is ready for your browser.

```
                    byte[] pdf = File.ReadAllBytes("C:/Users/skilic/Desktop/1.pdf");
                
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=MyFile.pdf");
                
                await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
                
                //context.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

I test it with just basic dotnet core web app.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't think I should use the Seek either, but the case is, that it doesn't work without it. Also, I'm unsure if it has something to do with the PDF's. The file size, perhaps? So it's a memory problem? Bottom line - with Seek I can open a file once and all the following will fail. Without Seek I can't open any files.